# manipulating the database concrete5

Tags: php, forms, concrete5

In concrete5 I'm trying to make a modal dialog with a form that must be filled out to view the page.  I have a form block for that. I also want people who've filled out the form before to be able to bypass it with their email(and count how many times they've accessed it).  I have an external form block for that.  How do I allow the external form to validate the email through the other forms list of emails, and increment a count field?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do this from the form block(s).

I can't think of any blocks that will get you near what you want. You will need to build this from scratch (or maybe a copy of the form block).

Comment: Yeah, I built it from scratch.  I used a template for the form so I could make a hidden view count field, then I just hacked it together.  Not very reusable, but it does the job.